# Stop R Shiny animation dead

Tags: r, animation, shiny

My Shiny animation app needs to do lot of plotting. I can change the animation interval for the plot using a control slider.

This reproducible example plots and animates random points :

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(frame_no = rep(1:500,10), x = runif(5000), y=runif(5000))

ui <- fluidPage(

sliderInput("frameInterval", "Set frame Interval (ms.)", min=0, 
max=2000, value=100,step=50),

uiOutput("frameSlider"),
plotOutput("plot.positions", height=500, width = 500) 
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

output$frameSlider <- renderUI( sliderInput("frame", label= h3("Animate"), 
          min=1, max = 5000, 
          value=1, step=1, sep=NULL,
          animate = animationOptions(interval = input$frameInterval, loop = 
          TRUE))
)

output$plot.positions <- renderPlot( {
    f <- filter(df, frame_no==input$frame)
    ggplot(f, aes(x=x, y=y)) + xlim(0,1) + ylim(0,1) +
    geom_point(aes(size=3)) +
    annotate("text", x= 0.5, y= 0.5, label=paste("Frame ", input$frame), 
    size=6)
},
bg="transparent"
  )
}
 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The problem I have is that when the animation interval is low (say 100ms) the plot lags behind the slider, as shown by comparing the slider value and the plotted frame number.

Then, if I want to pause the animation by clicking the slider pause, the display continues running until it catches up again with the slider value.

Is there any way to stop the animation instantly, even if it is lagging behind?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: This question has now been answered here https://community.rstudio.com/t/stop-shiny-animation-instantly/8709?u=istat